# Powershell operators

Tags: powershell, csv

What this script is doing is filtering Out certain operating systems at first. Then I am trying to make it filter out the Client Version with anything that starts with 14. I recently ran the following and it still shows Version 12 along with version 14.

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\SEPM Exports\Computer Status Export 7_13_2017.csv' 
$csv | Select "Version", "Operating System","Client Version","Policy Version","Computer Name","Computer Domain Name","Current login domain", "Current User" |
Where{"Windows 7 Enterprise Edition","Windows 10 Enterprise Edition","Windows 7 Professional Edition" -contains $_.'Operating System' -or $_.'Client Version' -like '14.*.****.****'} |
Export-Csv "C:\Users\eh3599\Desktop\SEPM Exports\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-ss)-Computer Status Export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

What can I change to make it filter only the Client Version 14?

[image: Client Version]

Comment: You could try using `-match "^14"` instead of `-contains`. That will try to match on specific characters.

Comment: `-contains` doesn't mean "does a string contain characters". It means "does a list contain an item".

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
"Client Version" -contains "14."
```

to this:

```
"Client Version" -like "14.*"
```

Reference: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-contains

Comment: On the other hand, you could shorten it considerably by using `-contains` correctly, such as: `Where{"Windows 7 Enterprise Edition","Windows 10 Enterprise Edition","Windows 7 Professional Edition" -contains $_.'Operating System' -or $_.'Client Version' -like '14*'}` That says if the list of OS's contains the OS for the current item, or the current item's Client Version starts with 14, then allow it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician When I did that, it did not filter the Client Version 14

Comment: You don't want client version 14? Then change `-like` to `-notlike`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Sprengdilly has started another thread for this issue. His real issue is that he wants his list to sort out on the OS AND and the Client Version, not OR Client Version. Not in the above noted requirements...